# Signal processing using CNN in tensorflow. TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'Tlabels' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: python, neural-network, signal-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to get a CNN to classify (two classes) exponential signals. For start I haven't split the data for train and validation, rather I am just trying to if I can train it or not.

I am having some difficulty understanding what are logits? are they the same thing as normalized data?

I have used this music genre classification and tried to see if I can adapt this model for my dataset.
 https://github.com/RobRomijnders/cnn_music/blob/master/CNN_music_main.py

I may be missing some parts of understanding, can anyone please help/suggest, where I am going wrong?

Here is the error I get after the step loss =     tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(h_fc2,y_)-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raisa/PycharmProjects/NN_model/patterns.py", line 96, in <module>
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(h_fc2,y_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 265, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    logits, labels, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 962, in _sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    features=features, labels=labels, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 486, in apply_op
_Attr(op_def, input_arg.type_attr))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 59, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'Tlabels' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code so far-

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import clip_ops
from bnf import *

#hyperparameters
Batch_size= 100
max_iteration= 50
learning_rate=1000
filt_1= [10,1,1]
num_fc_1 = 10
dropout = 0.5
num_classes = 2

#training data
lorange= 1
hirange= 15
amplitude= 10
t= 10
random.seed()
tau=np.random.uniform(lorange,hirange)

def generate_data(randomsignal):
    X= np.arange(t)
    Y= amplitude*np.exp(-X/tauA)
    return X, Y


#tensors for input data

X= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None, 10])
y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None])
Y_class= tf.argmax(y_, dimension=1)
bn_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder('float', name = 'dropout_keep_prob')

def weight_variable(shape, name):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial, name = name)

def bias_variable(shape, name):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial, name = name)



def conv2d(X, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(X, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.name_scope("Reshaping_data") as scope:
  X_node = tf.reshape(X, [-1,2,1,1])


with tf.name_scope("Conv1") as scope:
  W_conv1 = weight_variable([filt_1[1], 1, 1, filt_1[0]], 'Conv_Layer_1')
  b_conv1 = bias_variable([filt_1[0]], 'bias_for_Conv_Layer_1')
  a_conv1 = conv2d(X_node, W_conv1) + b_conv1
  h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(a_conv1)


with tf.name_scope('max_pool1') as scope:
    h_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv1, ksize=[1, filt_1[2], 1, 1],
                        strides=[1, filt_1[2], 1, 1], padding='VALID')

    width_pool1 = int(np.floor((10-filt_1[2])/filt_1[2]))+1
    size1 = tf.shape(h_pool1)

with tf.name_scope('Batch_norm1') as scope:
    a_bn1 = batch_norm(h_pool1,filt_1[0],bn_train,'bn')
    h_bn1 = tf.nn.relu(a_bn1)

with tf.name_scope("Fully_Connected1") as scope:
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([width_pool1 * filt_1[0], num_fc_1], 'Fully_Connected_layer_1')
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([num_fc_1], 'bias_for_Fully_Connected_Layer_1')
    h_flat = tf.reshape(h_bn1, [-1, width_pool1 * filt_1[0]])
    h_flat = tf.nn.dropout(h_flat, keep_prob)
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)



with tf.name_scope("Output_layer") as scope:
  h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
  W_fc2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_fc_1, num_classes], stddev=0.1),name = 'W_fc2')
  b_fc2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]),name = 'b_fc2')
  h_fc2 = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
size3 = tf.shape(h_fc2)

with tf.name_scope("SoftMax") as scope:
  loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(h_fc2,y_)
  cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
  loss_summ = tf.scalar_summary("cross entropy_loss", cost)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the complete traceback—or at least specify which line of code causes the error.

Comment: Hi I have edited the question and have added the traceback. Basically this error occurs after I try to compute softmax and cross entropy-

 loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(h_fc2,y_)

Comment: The error is saying you're passing in something that has 32-bit floating point values but only 32 or 64-bit integers are acceptable. I suspect it's because of the `y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None])` line—so try changing the first argument to `tf.int32`. If that's undesirable, try converting all the `float32` values into the latter just before the call.

Comment: I tried changing the placeholders into -

`X= tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape= [None, 10])`
`y_= tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape= [None])`

but now error is **TypeError: DataType int32 for attr 'T' not in list of allowed values: float32, float64**

Comment: Well, then only change the one for `y_` as I suggested...leave `X` alone.

Comment: Here's a definition of [**logit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit). Also see the question [_difference between tensorflow tf.nn.softmax and tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/difference-between-tensorflow-tf-nn-softmax-and-tf-nn-softmax-cross-entropy-with).

Comment: I got rid of the error by changing the unknown batch size of y_ to tf.int32... thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Good to hear and you're welcome.Sorry I didn't just post that as an answer myself, but I don't have all those libraries installed and don't like posting untested code. You can post it an answer to your own question (and even accept it) if you think it might be helpful to others.

Comment: @martineau  i was going to post the full code, but I still have to make some adjustments because it not fully working. 

Right now the issue is, I am giving a numpy array of shape (,10) as the input....but I need to convert it to a 4d tensor for the Conv and max pool layers. I am using **X_node = tf.reshape(X_node, [-1,2,1,1])**, but seems like I can't reshape it like this. So i have just posted a different question about this
 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824379/cannot-reshape-input-shape-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

your true labels must be in int32 or int64 format, so change the y_ to

`y_= tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape= [None])`