# Difference between Tensorflow and Scikitlearn log_loss function implementation

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, scikit-learn, loss

Hi I am trying to get into tensorflow and feeling a bit dumb.
Does log_loss in TF differ from sklearn's one?

Here are some lines from my code, how I am calculating:

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

tmp = np.array(y_test)
y_test_t = np.array([tmp, -(tmp-1)]).T[0]

tf_log_loss = tf.losses.log_loss(predictions=tf.nn.softmax(logits), labels=tf_y)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # training

    a = sess.run(tf.nn.softmax(logits), feed_dict={tf_x: xtest, keep_prob: 1.})
    print("    sk.log_loss: ", log_loss(y_test, a,eps=1e-7 ))
    print("    tf.log_loss: ", sess.run(tf_log_loss, feed_dict={tf_x: xtest, tf_y: y_test_t, keep_prob: 1.}))
```

Output I get

```
Epoch  7, Loss:     0.4875 Validation Accuracy: 0.818981
    sk.log_loss:  1.76533018874
    tf.log_loss:  0.396557
Epoch  8, Loss:     0.4850 Validation Accuracy: 0.820738
    sk.log_loss:  1.77217639627
    tf.log_loss:  0.393351
Epoch  9, Loss:     0.4835 Validation Accuracy: 0.823374
    sk.log_loss:  1.78479079656
    tf.log_loss:  0.390572
```

Seems like while `tf.log_loss` converges `sk.log_loss` diverges.

Comment: A question regarding this function. Can it be used with an autoencoder? i.e. the predictions and labels both be equal-size images?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. After looking up the source code of [tf.losses.log_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/log_loss), its [key lines](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py#L309-L312) show wat is going on:

```
losses = - math_ops.multiply(labels, math_ops.log(predictions + epsilon))
    - math_ops.multiply((1 - labels), math_ops.log(1 - predictions + epsilon))
```

It is **binary log-loss** (i.e. every class is considered non-exclusive) rather than **multi-class log-loss**.

As I worked with probabilities (rather than logits), I couldn't use [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) (though, I could have applied logarithm).
My solution was to implement log-loss by hand:

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(- labels, tf.log(probs))) / len(probs)
```

See also:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2462
- [difference between tensorflow tf.nn.softmax and tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/difference-between-tensorflow-tf-nn-softmax-and-tf-nn-softmax-cross-entropy-with)