# Why is doing softmax and crossentropy separately produce different result than doing them together using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was making a computer to predict a hand-written number from MNist data set using softmax function. and something weird happened. the cost was decreasing over time and eventually becomes something around 0.0038....(I used softmax_crossentropy_with_logits() for the cost function) However, the accuracy was pretty as low as 33%. So I thought "well.. I don't know what happened there but if I do softmax and crossentropy separately maybe it will produce different result !" and boom ! accuracy went up to 89 %. I have no idea why doing softmax and crossentropy separately makes such different result. I even looked up here :[difference between tensorflow tf.nn.softmax and tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/difference-between-tensorflow-tf-nn-softmax-and-tf-nn-softmax-cross-entropy-with)

so this is the code that I used softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() for the cost function (accuracy: 33%)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,784],dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,10],dtype=tf.float32)

W1= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,20]))
b1= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20]))
layer1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X,W1)+b1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20,10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))

logits = tf.matmul(layer1,W2)+b2
hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(logits) # just so I can figure our the accuracy 

cost_i= tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=Y)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost_i)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)


batch_size  = 100
train_epoch = 25
display_step = 1
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for epoch in range(train_epoch):
        av_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)
        for batch in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={X:batch_xs,Y:batch_ys})
        av_cost  += sess.run(cost,feed_dict={X:batch_xs,Y:batch_ys})/total_batch
        if epoch % display_step == 0:  # Softmax
            print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(av_cost))
    print ("Optimization Finished!")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis,1),tf.argmax(Y,1))
    accuray = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,'float32'))
    print("Accuracy:",sess.run(accuray,feed_dict={X:mnist.test.images,Y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

and this is the one that I did softmax and cross_entropy separately(accuracy: 89%)

```
import tensorflow as tf  #89 % accuracy one 
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,784],dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,10],dtype=tf.float32)

W1= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,20]))
b1= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20]))
layer1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X,W1)+b1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20,10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))


#logits = tf.matmul(layer1,W2)+b2
#cost_i= tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=Y)

logits = tf.matmul(layer1,W2)+b2

hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(-Y*tf.log(hypothesis)))


optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

batch_size  = 100
train_epoch = 25
display_step = 1
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for epoch in range(train_epoch):
        av_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)
        for batch in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={X:batch_xs,Y:batch_ys})
        av_cost  += sess.run(cost,feed_dict={X:batch_xs,Y:batch_ys})/total_batch
        if epoch % display_step == 0:  # Softmax
            print ("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(av_cost))
    print ("Optimization Finished!")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis,1),tf.argmax(Y,1))
    accuray = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,'float32'))
    print("Accuracy:",sess.run(accuray,feed_dict={X:mnist.test.images,Y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `tf.reduce_sum()` in the upper example, as you did in the lower one, you should be able to achieve similar results with both methods: `cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y)))`.

I increased the number of training epochs to 50 and achieved accuracies of 93.06% (`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`) and 93.24% (softmax and cross entropy separately), so the results are quite similar.

Comment: It works like a charm
 I thought cost_i= tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=Y) and 
tf.reduce_sum(-Y*tf.log(hypothesis)) was a same thing

Answer (score 2):

From Tensorflow API [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners#training) the second way, `cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(-Y*tf.log(hypothesis)))` is numerically unstable, and because of that you can't get same results,

Whatever, you can find on my [GitHub](https://github.com/AliAbbasi/Numerically-Stable-Cross-Entropy-Loss-Function-Tensorflow) the implementation of numerically stable cross entropy loss function which has the same result as `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` function.

You can see that `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` doesn't calculate the large numbers softmax normalization, on only approximate them, more details are in [README](https://github.com/AliAbbasi/Numerically-Stable-Cross-Entropy-Loss-Function-Tensorflow/blob/master/README.md) section.