# PyTorch equivalent to tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits and tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, softmax

I found the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218566/pytorch-equivalence-for-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits). Here, we try to find an equivalence of `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in PyTorch. The answer is still confusing to me.

Here is the `Tensorflow 2` code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# here we assume 2 batch size with 5 classes

preds = np.array([[.4, 0, 0, 0.6, 0], [.8, 0, 0, 0.2, 0]])
labels = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0], [1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


tf_preds = tf.convert_to_tensor(preds, dtype=tf.float32)
tf_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.float32)

loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=tf_preds, labels=tf_labels)
```

It give me the `loss` as

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.2427604, 1.0636061], dtype=float32)>
```

Here is the `PyTorch` code

```
import torch
import numpy as np

preds = np.array([[.4, 0, 0, 0.6, 0], [.8, 0, 0, 0.2, 0]])
labels = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0], [1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


torch_preds = torch.tensor(preds).float()
torch_labels = torch.tensor(labels).float()

loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(torch_preds, torch_labels)
```

However, it raises:

> RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

It seems that the problem is still unsolved. How to implement `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in PyTorch?

What about `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### - `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

*Edit:* This is actually not equivalent to [`F.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html?highlight=cross_entropy#torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy). The latter can only handle the single-class classification setting. Not the more general case of multi-class classification, whereby the label can be comprised of multiple classes. Indeed, [`F.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html?highlight=cross_entropy#torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy) takes a unique class id as target (per instance), **not a probability distribution over classes** as `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` can expect to receive.

```
>>> logits = torch.tensor([[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [0.0, 5.0, 1.0]])
>>> labels = torch.tensor([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.8, 0.2]])
```

In order to get the desired result apply a log-softmax to your logits then take the negative log-likelihood:

```
>>> -torch.sum(F.log_softmax(logits, dim=1) * labels, dim=1)
tensor([0.1698, 0.8247])
```

---

### - `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`

For this one you can apply [`F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits.html?highlight=f%20binary_cross_entropy_with_logits#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits).

```
>>> F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, reduction='none')
tensor([[0.0181, 2.1269, 1.3133],
        [0.6931, 1.0067, 1.1133]])
```

It is equivalent to applying a sigmoid then the negative log-likelihood, considering each class as a binary classification task:

```
>>> labels*-torch.log(torch.sigmoid(logits)) + (1-labels)*-torch.log(1-torch.sigmoid(logits))
tensor([[0.0181, 2.1269, 1.3133],
        [0.6931, 1.0067, 1.1133]])
```

---

*having imported `torch.nn.functional` as `F`*.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Any idea how to implement `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` in Pytorch?

Comment: That was trickier than I thought! But here it is ;) See my edited answer. Also I have taken the liberty of editing your post to expand your question, for other users who might be interested...

Comment: The results doesn't match for softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits for this example: preds = [[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [0.0, 5.0, 1.0]]
labels = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.8, 0.2]]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it is true `torch.nn.cross_entropy` is not equivalent to `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, since the latter handles the more general case of multi-class classification, i.e. with multiple labels as target. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The [nn.CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) outputs the same as `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

```py
>>> import torch

>>> loss_fct = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')

>>> preds = np.array([[.4, 0, 0, 0.6, 0], [.8, 0, 0, 0.2, 0]])
>>> labels = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0], [1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

>>> preds = torch.from_numpy(preds)
>>> labels = torch.from_numpy(labels)

>>> loss_fct(preds, labels)
tensor([1.2428, 1.0636], dtype=torch.float64)
```

The `reduction` param defaults to mean. I made it `none` to match your output.

[nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) outputs the same as `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`

```
>>> tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=tf_preds, labels=tf_labels)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.91301525, 0.6931472 , 0.6931472 , 0.43748793, 0.6931472 ],
       [0.37110066, 0.6931472 , 0.6931472 , 0.79813886, 0.6931472 ]],
      dtype=float32)>

>>> loss_fct = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='none')
>>> loss_fct(preds, labels, )
tensor([[0.9130, 0.6931, 0.6931, 0.4375, 0.6931],
        [0.3711, 0.6931, 0.6931, 0.7981, 0.6931]], dtype=torch.float64)
```