# How to use soft labels in computer vision with PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision

I have an image dataset with soft labels (i.e. the images don't belong to a single class, but rather I have a probability distribution saying that there's a 66% chance this image belong in one class and 33% chance it belongs in some other class).

I am struggling to figure out how to setup my PyTorch code to allow this to be represented by the model and outputted correctly. The probabilities are saved in a csv file. I have looked at the PyTorch docs and other resources which mention the cross entropy loss function but I am still unclear how to import the data successfully and make use of soft labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to solve is a multi-label classification task, *i.e.* instances can be classified with more than one label at a time. You cannot use [`torch.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) since it only allows for single-label targets. So you have two options:

- Either use a soft version of the [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=cross%20entropy#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) function, this can be done by implementing the loss by hand allowing for soft targets. You can find such implementation on [*Soft Cross Entropy in PyTorch*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907809/soft-cross-entropy-in-pytorch/68914806#68914806).
- Or consider the task a multiple "independent" binary classification tasks, in this case, you would use [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html?highlight=bce#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) (this layer contains a *sigmoid* function).

Comment: I think his task is still a single-label classification as long as the probabilities sum up to one.

Answer (score 1):

### Pytorch CrossEntropyLoss Supports Soft Labels Natively Now

Thanks to the Pytorch team, I believe this problem has been solved with the current version of the torch [CROSSENTROPYLOSS](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#crossentropyloss).
You can **directly input probabilities for each class as target** (see the doc).

Here is the [forum discussion](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/11959) that pushed this enhancement.