# MNIST Classification: low accuracy (10%) and no change in loss

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, tensorboard, mnist

I'm learning TensorFlow and tired to apply on mnist database.
My question is (see attached image) :

- what could cause such output for accuracy (improving and then degrading!) & Loss (almost constant!)
- the accuracy isn't that great just hovering around 10%

[image: Accuracy / Loss - Tensorboard]]

Despite:

- 5 layer network (incl. output layer), with 200/10/60/30/10 neurons respectively
- Is the network not learning ? despite 0.1 learning rate (which is quite high I believe)

Full code: https://github.com/vibhorj/tf > mnist-2.py

1) here's how the layers are defined:

```
K,L,M,N=200,100,60,30
""" Layer 1 """
with tf.name_scope('L1'):
    w1 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([28*28,K],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w1')
    b1 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([K],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'b1')
""" Layer 2 """
with tf.name_scope('L2'):
    w2 = tf.Variable(initial_value =tf.truncated_normal([K,L],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w2')
    b2 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([L],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'b2')
""" Layer 3 """
with tf.name_scope('L3'):
    w3 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([L,M],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w3')
    b3 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([M],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'b3')
""" Layer 4 """
with tf.name_scope('L4'):
    w4 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([M,N],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w4')
    b4 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([N],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'b4')
""" Layer output """
with tf.name_scope('L_out'):
    w_out = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([N,10],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w_out')
    b_out = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([10],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'b_out')
```

2) loss function

```
Y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(X,w1),b1), name='Y1')
Y2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(Y1,w2),b2), name='Y2')
Y3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(Y2,w3),b3), name='Y3')
Y4 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(Y3,w4),b4), name='Y4')

Y_pred_logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(Y4, w_out),b_out,name='logits')
Y_pred_prob = tf.nn.softmax(Y_pred_logits, name='probs')

error = -tf.matmul(Y
              , tf.reshape(tf.log(Y_pred_prob),[10,-1]), name ='err')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(error, name = 'loss')
```

3) optimization function

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
ctr = tf.Variable(0.0, name='ctr')
z = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=ctr)
```

4)  Tensorboard code:

```
evt_file = tf.summary.FileWriter('/Users/vibhorj/python/-tf/g_mnist')
evt_file.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

s1 = tf.summary.scalar(name='accuracy', tensor=accuracy)
s2 = tf.summary.scalar(name='loss', tensor=loss)
m1 = tf.summary.merge([s1,s2])
```

5) run the session (test data is mnist.test.images & mnist.test.labels

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables()))
    for i in range(300):
       """ calc. accuracy on test data - TENSORBOARD before iteration beings """
       summary = sess.run(m1, feed_dict=test_data)
       evt_file.add_summary(summary, sess.run(ctr))
       evt_file.flush()

       """ fetch train data """        
       a_train, b_train = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size=100)
       train_data = {X: a_train , Y: b_train}

       """ train """
       sess.run(z, feed_dict = train_data)
```

Appreciate your time to provide any insight into it. I'm completely clueless hwo to proceed further (even tried initializing w & b with random_normal, played with learning rates [0.1,0.01, 0.001])

Cheers!

Comment: Would you have a Gist or public repo we can checkout to find the issue? I had a quick review, but it is time-consuming to go through such code on this page. Review so far: Perhaps something with the name scopes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for look at it! https://github.com/vibhorj/tf > mnist-2.py

Comment: Basic questions: (1) How does your architecture compare to classic MNIST solutions?  (2) Is there a similar, wider topology that trains well?  For instance, what happens if you change the second layer from 10 to 30 neurons?  These checks will help narrow the problem (eliminate the topology as the problem).

Comment: There is public example for TF and MNiST, please read the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider

1. Initializing biases to zeros
2. Using ReLU units instead of sigmoid - avoid saturation
3. Using Adam optimizer - faster learning

I feel that your network is quite large. You could do with a smaller network.

```
K,L,M,N=200,100,60,30
""" Layer 1 """
with tf.name_scope('L1'):
    w1 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([28*28,K],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w1')
    b1 = tf.zeros([K])#tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([K],mean=0,stddev=0.01), name = 'b1')
""" Layer 2 """
with tf.name_scope('L2'):
    w2 = tf.Variable(initial_value =tf.truncated_normal([K,L],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w2')
    b2 = tf.zeros([L])#tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([L],mean=0,stddev=0.01), name = 'b2')
""" Layer 3 """
with tf.name_scope('L3'):
    w3 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([L,M],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w3')
    b3 = tf.zeros([M]) #tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([M],mean=0,stddev=0.01), name = 'b3')
""" Layer 4 """
with tf.name_scope('L4'):
    w4 = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([M,N],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w4')
    b4 = tf.zeros([N])#tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([N],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'b4')
""" Layer output """
with tf.name_scope('L_out'):
    w_out = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([N,10],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'w_out')
    b_out = tf.zeros([10])#tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.truncated_normal([10],mean=0,stddev=0.1), name = 'b_out')


Y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X,w1),b1), name='Y1')
Y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(Y1,w2),b2), name='Y2')
Y3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(Y2,w3),b3), name='Y3')
Y4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(Y3,w4),b4), name='Y4')

Y_pred_logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(Y4, w_out),b_out,name='logits')

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y, logits=Y_pred_logits, name='xentropy'))
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
ctr = tf.Variable(0.0, name='ctr', trainable=False)
train_op = opt.minimize(loss, global_step=ctr)

for v in tf.trainable_variables():
  print v.op.name

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables()))
    for i in range(3000):
       """ calc. accuracy on test data - TENSORBOARD before iteration beings """
       #summary = sess.run(m1, feed_dict=test_data)
       #evt_file.add_summary(summary, sess.run(ctr))
       #evt_file.flush()

       """ fetch train data """
       a_train, b_train = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size=100)
       train_data = {X: a_train , Y: b_train}

       """ train """
       l = sess.run(loss, feed_dict = train_data)
       print l
       sess.run(train_op, feed_dict = train_data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the tip. After 1) initializing bias to 0, 2) Activation RELU except output layer loss is *nan* and no change to accuracy (9.79%). EVen lowered learning rate to 0.00001

Comment: Can you please share your latest code? I can see the loss going down for the code I posted above.

Comment: here you go https://github.com/vibhorj/tf/blob/master/so-changes/mnist-2-so.py Thanks a lot! Interesting, the code looks very similar but loss goes down in your in not in mind.. could it be because I'm not using in-built function tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() for loss calculation?

Comment: May I ask why you recommend to initialise bias to 0? what implications it has.. most people say to use random values for initialisations..

Comment: It's customary. For relu units a small positive value might be good since it would ensure that gradients flow initially.

Comment: For your NaN loss, the function I used is numerically stable. You can Google for discussion on this. BTW could you kindly consider upvoting if the solution above helped?

Comment: Thanks for clarifications re: RELU. but I;m still confused why your code works (loss goes down) but mine doesn't, they both almost same!  could it be because I'm not using in-built function tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() for loss calculation?

Comment: Please see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/difference-between-tensorflow-tf-nn-softmax-and-tf-nn-softmax-cross-entropy-with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159259/discussion-between-vibhor-jain-and-dgumo).