# Tensorflow - softmax returning only 0 and 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, softmax, cross-entropy

I'm training a CNN on tensorflow but I'm having trouble with my loss that is not improving; I've noticed that `tf.nn.softmax()` is returning a tensor with only 0 and 1 and not a distribution as I'd expect. [Here's the repo](https://github.com/alegaballo/AlexNet_CNN/blob/master/AlexNet.ipynb), I believe that's the reason of my incapability of training the network but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the 2nd box under **The Neural Network**:

```
# output layer
with tf.variable_scope('output_lay') as scope:
    weights = weight_variable([4096, CLASSES])
    bias = bias_variable([CLASSES], 0.)
    activation = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(out, weights)+bias, name=scope.name)
    out = tf.nn.softmax(activation)
return tf.reshape(out, [-1, CLASSES])
```

**NB : `ReLu` activation is only used for hidden layers not output layer.**

Then you are feeding this to cross-entropy in your `train` function

```
logits=AlexNet(x_tr)

# loss function
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.squeeze(y_tr)*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(tf.squeeze(logits),1e-10,1.0)))
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
```

Re-visiting [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification#Cross_entropy_loss_(Log_Loss)):

`C= −1/n * (∑[y*ln(a)+(1−y)*ln(1−a)])`

where `a = sigmoid(W(x)+b)`, So I suggest :

```
with tf.variable_scope('output_lay') as scope:
    weights = weight_variable([4096, CLASSES])
    bias = bias_variable([CLASSES], 0.)
    return tf.matmul(out, weights)+bias
```

and for simplicity just use inbuilt softmax function:

```
logits=AlexNet(x_tr)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=ground_truth_input, logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
```

`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` takes in `W(x)+b` and efficiently calculates the cross entropy.

Comment: I think you're right about the ReLu in the output layer, I've tried using `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` but I get `nan` for the loss. If I use my own way to compute it, then the problem of the softmax giving only 0 or 1 remains

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo is your `ground_truth_input` **One-hot** encoded ?

Comment: Yes, In the `decode()` method I do `label = tf.one_hot(label, 10)`

Comment: In that case just input the raw `W(x)+b` to `tf.nn.softmax` (it internally takes care of applying sigmoid to `W(x)+b`)and see if that helps.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/whats-the-difference-between-softmax-and-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits#answer-39499486) may be of some help.

Comment: As I've mentioned, if I output `tf.nn.softmax()` and compute the cross entropy manually, I get all 0 and 1 in the predictions, if I use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` to compute the loss, I get nan. In both cases the loss doesn't improve