# Should I use softmax or tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits to generate a multi class classification with a probability per class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm reading about NN, and would also like to generate my first NN at the same time (to complement my reading).

I have a data set like this:

```
DNA_seq  Sample1Name  Sample1Name  ConcOfDNAInSample  DNASeqFoundInProcessCat

AGGAG     cat_0     cat_1    0.1   found_in_0  
AGGAG     cat_1     cat_2    0.4   found_in_3
ACCCC     cat_1     cat_7    0.1   found_in_2
AGAGAGA   cat_2     cat_10   1.9   found_in_1
ADAS      cat_332   cat_103  8.9   found_in_1
```

Columns:

> 1. DNASeq -> a string of a DNA sequence (i.e. 'the sequences')
> 2. Sample1Name -> categorical value explaining a chemical property of the solution that DNASeq is in.
> 3. Sample2Name -> categorical value explaining a chemical property of the solution that DNASeq is in.
> 4. ConcOfDNAInSample -> a quantitative value of DNA concentration in Sample2SName.
> 5. DNASeqFoundInProcessCat -> This is the label that I want to predict. It is a categorical value with four categories (found_in_0 -> found_in_3). This is the output from where I did three tests on each DNASeq to see if I manipulate the original solution (which is the found_in_0), is the DNASeq still present.

My question:
For an unseen set of sequences, I want the output set of labels to be a multi-class probability of 'found_in_1', 'found_in_2', 'found_in_3'.

i.e. if the above example was the output from my test set, my output would ideally look like this:

```
DNA_seq  Sample1Name  Sample1Name  ConcOfDNAInSample  DNASeqFoundInProcessCat

AGGAG     cat_0     cat_1    0.1   (0.9,0.5,0.1)  
AGGAG     cat_1     cat_2    0.4   (0.8,0.7,0.3)
ACCCC     cat_1     cat_7    0.1   (0.2,0.5,0.3)
AGAGAGA   cat_2     cat_10   1.9   (0.7,0.2,0.9)
ADAS      cat_332   cat_103  8.9   (0.6,0.8,0.7)
```

There are some notes:

1. It is possible that because of the processes I am doing, that some sequences can NOT be in the original solution (found_in_0), but then because bits of DNA can stick together, they CAN subsequently be in the other classes (found_in_1, found_in_2, found_in_3)
2. I am only interested in the output for the found_in_1, found_in_2 and found_in_3 class (i.e. I want a three class probability at the end, not a four class probability with found_in_0).
3. I am able to generate other features from the DNA seqs, this is just an example.
4. I can see from my data, that my data set is unbalanced, the amount of data in found_in_3 is significantly lower than the others (my full training data is about 80,000 rows; but only about 10,000 of these rows are found_in_3; the others are all found_in_0, found_in_1 or found_in_2).

What I'm trying to work out is the algorithm, for one specific point in particular. My idea was:

1.Read in the data.

`df = pd.read_csv('data')`

2.Split the data set into train and test

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
```

3.Understand the data set (i.e. that's where I saw the under-representation in point 4, above).
I have a series of functions for this...so let's say I have a standardised data set which is the table above.

4.Build neural network.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
```

I know the general idea here would be the tensorflow equivalent of doing this in keras (i.e. this is for the 'iris' data set; where I initialise a model, add some layers and an activation function, compile the model,generate an output of the model and then fit the model and then predict after this (not shown)):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8,input_dim=4,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8,input_dim=4,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=150,verbose=0)
```

So I understand I want to replicate a similar set of steps for my data, and I'm trying to work out how to do this, what I can't understand is do I have to use tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits for this problem (since each input can belong to move than one label, i.e. can be present in found_in_1, found_in_2 and found_in_3, this can produce a probability output per class?)

Or can I just use a softmax function like [this](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/guide-to-multi-label-classification-with-neural-networks/)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental difference between `softmax` and `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`. The first one applies [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function. In essence, you provide on the input unnormalised scores (logits) and outputs normalised values that can be interpreted as probabilities.

On the other hand, `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` will first get you a sigmoid and then compute cross entropy (against `labales`, its first argument!) in a numerically stable way.

More detailed explanation can be found e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/what-is-logits-softmax-and-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits). I guess what you are after is `softmax`.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: assuming you have multiple classes/labels, does each sample belong to exactly one class (has exactly one label)?

**Yes:** multiclass. Use softmax for activation and [sparse] categorical cross entropy for loss.

**No**, object can belong to multiple classes simultaneously: multilabel. Use sigmoid for activation and binary cross entropy for loss.

From the description, I'm not certain what is the case in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If each input can belong to more than one label/class, you need to use `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`. If you use `sigmoid` on model output you will get `3` probabilities for `3` labels. You can read more details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits).