# Selecting loss and metrics for Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to do transfer learning, using a pretrained **Xception** model with a newly added classifier.

This is the model:

```
base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(224,224,3),
    include_top=False
)
```

The dataset I'm using is `oxford_flowers102` taken directly from tensorflow datasets.
[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/oxford_flowers102) is a dataset page.

**I have a problem with selecting some parameters** - either training accuracy shows suspiciously low values, or there's an error.

I need help with specifying this parameter, for this (oxford_flowers102) dataset:

1. Newly added dense layer for the classifier. I was trying with:
   `outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102, activation='softmax')(x)` and I'm not sure whether I should select the activation function here or not.
2. loss function for model.
3. metrics.

I tried:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()],
)
```

I'm not sure whether it should be `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` or `CategoricalCrossentropy`, and what about `from_logits` parameter?

I'm also not sure whether should I choose for metrics`keras.metrics.Accuracy()` or `keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()`

I am definitely lacking some theoretical knowledge, but right now I just need this to work. Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### About the data set: [oxford_flowers102](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/oxford_flowers102)

The dataset is divided into a **training set**, a **validation set**, and a **test set**. The training set and validation set each consist of **10** images per class (totaling **1020** images each). The test set consists of the remaining **6149** images (minimum **20** per class).

```
'test'        6,149
'train'       1,020
'validation'  1,020
```

If we check, we'll see

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.disable_progress_bar()

data, ds_info = tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', 
                          with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_ds, valid_ds, test_ds = data['train'], data['validation'], data['test']

for i, data in enumerate(train_ds.take(3)):
  print(i+1, data[0].shape, data[1])
1 (500, 667, 3) tf.Tensor(72, shape=(), dtype=int64)
2 (500, 666, 3) tf.Tensor(84, shape=(), dtype=int64)
3 (670, 500, 3) tf.Tensor(70, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

```
ds_info.features["label"].num_classes
102
```

So, it has **102** categories or classes and the target comes with an **integer** with different shapes input.

### Clarification

**First**, if you keep this integer target or label, you should use [`sparse_categorical_accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SparseCategoricalAccuracy) for accuracy and [`sparse_categorical_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) for loss function. But if you transform your integer label to a **one-hot encoded vector**, then you should use [`categorical_accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/categorical_accuracy) for accuracy, and [`categorical_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/categorical_crossentropy) for loss function. As these data set have integer labels, you can choose `sparse_categorical` or you can transform the label to one-hot in order to use `categorical`.

**Second**, if you set `outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102, activation='softmax')(x)` to the last layer, you will get **probabilities score**. But if you set `outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102)(x)`, then you will get **logits**. So, if you set `activations='softmax'`, then you should not use `from_logit = True`. For example in your above code you should do as follows (here's [some theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/what-are-logits-what-is-the-difference-between-softmax-and-softmax-cross-entrop) for you):

```
...
(a)
# Use softmax activation (no logits output)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102, activation='softmax')(x)
...
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()],
)

or,

(b)
# no activation, output will be logits
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102)(x)
...
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()],
)
```

**Third**, [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) uses **string identifier** such as `metrics=['acc'] , optimizer='adam'`. But in your case, you need to be a bit more specific as you mention loss function specific. So, instead of `keras.metrics.Accuracy()`, you should choose `keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()` **if you target are integer** or `keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()` **if your target are one-hot encoded vector**.

### Code Examples

Here is an end-to-end example. Note, I will **transform integer labels to a one-hot encoded vector** (right now, it's a matter of preference to me). Also, I want **probabilities** (not logits) from the last layer which means `from_logits = False`. And for all of these, I need to choose the following parameters in my training:

```
# use softmax to get probabilities 
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102, 
                   activation='softmax')(x)

# so no logits, set it false (FYI, by default it already false)
loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),

# specify the metrics properly 
metrics = keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
```

Let's complete the whole code.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.disable_progress_bar()

data, ds_info = tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', 
                         with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_ds, valid_ds, test_ds = data['train'], data['validation'], data['test']


NUM_CLASSES = ds_info.features["label"].num_classes
train_size =  len(data['train'])

batch_size = 64
img_size = 120
```

**Preprocess and Augmentation**

```
import tensorflow as tf 

# pre-process functions 
def normalize_resize(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.divide(image, 255)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (img_size, img_size))
    label = tf.one_hot(label , depth=NUM_CLASSES) # int to one-hot
    return image, label

# augmentation 
def augment(image, label):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    return image, label 


train = train_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().map(augment).shuffle(100).\
                          batch(batch_size).repeat()
valid = valid_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().batch(batch_size)
test = test_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().batch(batch_size)
```

**Model**

```
from tensorflow import keras 

base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',  
    input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3),
    include_top=False)  

base_model.trainable = False
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Okay, additionally, here I like to use two metrics to compute [`top-1`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/TopKCategoricalAccuracy) and [`top-3`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/TopKCategoricalAccuracy) accuracy.

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[
                       keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=3, name='acc_top3'),
                       keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=1, name='acc_top1')
                    ])
model.fit(train, steps_per_epoch=train_size // batch_size,
          epochs=20, validation_data=valid, verbose=2)
```

```
...
Epoch 19/20
15/15 - 2s - loss: 0.2808 - acc_top3: 0.9979 - acc_top1: 0.9917 - 
val_loss: 1.5025 - val_acc_top3: 0.8147 - val_acc_top1: 0.6186

Epoch 20/20
15/15 - 2s - loss: 0.2743 - acc_top3: 0.9990 - acc_top1: 0.9885 - 
val_loss: 1.4948 - val_acc_top3: 0.8147 - val_acc_top1: 0.6255
```

**Evaluate**

```
# evaluate on test set 
model.evaluate(test, verbose=2)
97/97 - 18s - loss: 1.6482 - acc_top3: 0.7733 - acc_top1: 0.5994
[1.648208498954773, 0.7732964754104614, 0.5994470715522766]
```