# Mismatch in the calculated and the actual values of Output of the Softmax Activation Function in the Output Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In the below code, I am comparing the **`Predicted Output`** of the **`TF Keras Model`** with the respective value which is **`calculated Manually`** (**`Softmax Activation`** implemented using **`Numpy`**).

Surprisingly, they are not same. Am I missing something?

Also, there is a Warning,

> UserWarning: "`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received
> `from_logits=True`, but the `output` argument was produced by a
> sigmoid or softmax activation and thus does not represent logits. Was
> this intended?"   '"`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received
> `from_logits=True`, but '

What does that warning mean? And is that warning the reason for the mismatch?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="predictions", activation = 'softmax')(x2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# Prepare the training dataset.
batch_size = 64
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

# Normalize the values of Pixels of Image. Else, Calculation of Softmax results in NaN
x_train = x_train/255.0
x_test = x_test/255.0

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation.
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

# Prepare the training dataset.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# Prepare the validation dataset.
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)

epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        
        x_batch_train = tf.cast(x_batch_train, tf.float32)               
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
        
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
        
        Initial_Weights_1st_Hidden_Layer = model.trainable_weights[0]
        
        Initial_Weights_2nd_Hidden_Layer = model.trainable_weights[2]
        
        Initial_Weights_Output_Layer = model.trainable_weights[4]
                
        Initial_Bias_1st_Hidden_Layer = model.trainable_weights[1]
        
        Initial_Bias_2nd_Hidden_Layer = model.trainable_weights[3]
        
        Initial_Bias_Output_Layer = model.trainable_weights[5]
        
        # Implementing Relu Activation Function using Numpy
        def Relu_Activation(Input):
            return np.maximum(Input, 0)
        
        #Compute Softmax Activation Function using Numpy
        def Softmax_Activation(Input):
            return np.exp(Input) / np.sum(np.exp(Input), axis=0)
        
        # Calculations
        Input_to_1st_Hidden_Layer = x_batch_train @ Initial_Weights_1st_Hidden_Layer + \
                                                                        Initial_Bias_1st_Hidden_Layer
                     
        Output_Of_1st_Hidden_Layer = Relu_Activation(Input_to_1st_Hidden_Layer)
        
        Input_to_2nd_Hidden_Layer = Output_Of_1st_Hidden_Layer @ Initial_Weights_2nd_Hidden_Layer + \
                                                                        Initial_Bias_2nd_Hidden_Layer
                   
        Output_Of_2nd_Hidden_Layer = Relu_Activation(Input_to_2nd_Hidden_Layer)
      
        Input_to_Final_Layer = Output_Of_2nd_Hidden_Layer @ Initial_Weights_Output_Layer + \
                                                                        Initial_Bias_Output_Layer
        
        # Softmax Activation Function has been used in the Output/Final Layer
        Calculated_Y_Pred = Softmax_Activation(Input_to_Final_Layer)

        # Log every 200 batches.
        if step == 200:
            print('\n Y_Pred = ', logits[0:2])
            print('\n Calculated_Y_Pred = ', Calculated_Y_Pred[0:2])
```

The output of the above code is shown below:

```py
Start of epoch 0
/home/mothukuru/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4930: UserWarning: "`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but the `output` argument was produced by a sigmoid or softmax activation and thus does not represent logits. Was this intended?"
  '"`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but '

 Y_Pred =  tf.Tensor(
[[0.07784345 0.13746074 0.09005958 0.08652461 0.07746054 0.12440132
  0.10698392 0.07508533 0.07116801 0.15301245]
 [0.0656803  0.08119027 0.09362638 0.10353054 0.12599334 0.10456354
  0.1271341  0.08623642 0.08971243 0.12233265]], shape=(2, 10), dtype=float32)

 Calculated_Y_Pred =  [[0.01511016 0.02304603 0.01961761 0.01425961 0.01025286 0.02124614
  0.01223315 0.01411171 0.01178642 0.01445299]
 [0.01271159 0.01357185 0.02033444 0.01701196 0.01662761 0.01780546
  0.01449438 0.01615969 0.01481383 0.01152103]]

Start of epoch 1

 Y_Pred =  tf.Tensor(
[[0.12411885 0.08815324 0.05189805 0.07208851 0.11877609 0.06383732
  0.13067529 0.08087374 0.09073243 0.17884655]
 [0.07584718 0.079349   0.06285123 0.1089478  0.09581042 0.09398626
  0.12189291 0.10832074 0.08284932 0.17014521]], shape=(2, 10), dtype=float32)

 Calculated_Y_Pred =  [[0.02525741 0.01648222 0.01210153 0.012623   0.01642019 0.01224833
  0.01583157 0.01587343 0.01606088 0.01728726]
 [0.01414648 0.01359805 0.01343262 0.01748529 0.01214003 0.01652816
  0.01353526 0.01948644 0.01344168 0.01507382]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting loss and metrics for Tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848962/selecting-loss-and-metrics-for-tensorflow-model)

Comment: Let me know if the answer solves your query.

Comment: Hello Innat, Thank you for your response but that answer doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I bet you didn't read properly, the warning message you get is, if not only but a serious reason. in your set up you shouldn't use softmax if you set from logit to True and vice versa.

Comment: The values are different even after removing `from_logits=True`

Answer (score 0):

### Clarification

**First**, if you keep this integer target or label, you should use sparse_categorical_accuracy for accuracy and sparse_categorical_crossentropy for loss function. But if you transform your integer label to a one-hot encoded vector, then you should use categorical_accuracy for accuracy, and categorical_crossentropy for loss function. As these data set have integer labels, you can choose sparse_categorical or you can transform the label to one-hot in order to use categorical.

**Second**, if you set outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102, activation='softmax')(x) to the last layer, you will get probabilities score. But if you set outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102)(x), then you will get logits. So, if you set activations='softmax', then you should not use from_logit = True. For example in your above code you should do as follows (here's some theory for you):

```
...
(a)
# Use softmax activation (no logits output)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102, activation='softmax')(x)
...
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()],
)
```

or,

```
(b)
# no activation, output will be logits
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102)(x)
...
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()],
)
```

**Third**, keras uses string identifier such as metrics=['acc'] , optimizer='adam'. But in your case, you need to be a bit more specific as you mention loss function specific. So, instead of keras.metrics.Accuracy(), you should choose keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy() if you target are integer or keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy() if your target are one-hot encoded vector.

#### Code Examples

Here is an end-to-end example. Note, I will transform integer labels to a one-hot encoded vector (right now, it's a matter of preference to me). Also, I want probabilities (not logits) from the last layer which means from_logits = False. And for all of these, I need to choose the following parameters in my training:

```
# use softmax to get probabilities 
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(102, 
                   activation='softmax')(x)

# so no logits, set it false (FYI, by default it already false)
loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),

# specify the metrics properly 
metrics = keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
```

Let's complete the whole code.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.disable_progress_bar()

data, ds_info = tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', 
                         with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_ds, valid_ds, test_ds = data['train'], data['validation'], data['test']


NUM_CLASSES = ds_info.features["label"].num_classes
train_size =  len(data['train'])

batch_size = 64
img_size = 120
```

Preprocess and Augmentation

```
import tensorflow as tf 

# pre-process functions 
def normalize_resize(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.divide(image, 255)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (img_size, img_size))
    label = tf.one_hot(label , depth=NUM_CLASSES) # int to one-hot
    return image, label

# augmentation 
def augment(image, label):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    return image, label 


train = train_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().map(augment).shuffle(100).\
                          batch(batch_size).repeat()
valid = valid_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().batch(batch_size)
test = test_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().batch(batch_size)
```

Model

```
from tensorflow import keras 

base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',  
    input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3),
    include_top=False)  

base_model.trainable = False
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Okay, additionally, here I like to use two metrics to compute top-1 and top-3 accuracy.

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[
                       keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=3, name='acc_top3'),
                       keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=1, name='acc_top1')
                    ])
model.fit(train, steps_per_epoch=train_size // batch_size,
          epochs=20, validation_data=valid, verbose=2)

...
Epoch 19/20
15/15 - 2s - loss: 0.2808 - acc_top3: 0.9979 - acc_top1: 0.9917 - 
val_loss: 1.5025 - val_acc_top3: 0.8147 - val_acc_top1: 0.6186

Epoch 20/20
15/15 - 2s - loss: 0.2743 - acc_top3: 0.9990 - acc_top1: 0.9885 - 
val_loss: 1.4948 - val_acc_top3: 0.8147 - val_acc_top1: 0.6255
```

Evaluate

```
# evaluate on test set 
model.evaluate(test, verbose=2)
97/97 - 18s - loss: 1.6482 - acc_top3: 0.7733 - acc_top1: 0.5994

[1.648208498954773, 0.7732964754104614, 0.5994470715522766]
```